# How to pivoting

Tags: sql-server

I just don't understanding pivoting and i need help on a simple query using `UNION`. My query gives me the results as fellows:

```
SELECT 
  'LuFt' AS [Source],
   SUM([SalesAmount1]) AS [Sales old],
   SUM([SalesAmount2]) AS [Sales new]
FROM [dbo].[tblSales]
WHERE ([Source] IN ('LuFt')) AND [Planung] = 'kosten'

UNION

SELECT 
  'TGL' AS [Source],
   SUM([SalesAmount1]) AS [Sales old],
   SUM([SalesAmount2]) AS [Sales new]
FROM [dbo].[tblSales]
WHERE ([Source] IN ('TGL')) AND [Planung] = 'kosten'

UNION

SELECT 
  'BHW' AS [Source],
   SUM([SalesAmount1]) AS [Sales old],
   SUM([SalesAmount2]) AS [Sales new]
FROM [dbo].[tblSales]
WHERE ([Source] IN ('BHW')) AND [Planung] = 'kosten'

UNION

SELECT 
   'WM ' AS [Source],
    SUM([SalesAmount1]) AS [Sales old],
    SUM([SalesAmount2]) AS [Sales new]
FROM [dbo].[tblSales]
WHERE ([Source] IN ('WM')) AND [Planung] = 'kosten'
```

Results:

```
[Source]      [Sales old]      [Sales new]
 Luft           10000            20000
 TGL            500              800
 BHW            1500             500
 WM             700              400
```

My Expectation using pivot:

```
[]          [Luft]   [TGL]  [BHW]  [WM]
Sales old    10000    500    1500   700
Sales new    20000    800    500    400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `union` appends the two select statements together. The reason that the results are how they are, is that you're selecting the source and the old/new sales as your columns.

For the desired output I would write it as below:

If you have any questions about the method or the query feel free to ask.

```
SELECT 
  'Sales old' AS [Category],
  SUM(Case when [Source] = 'Luft' then [SalesAmount1] else 0 end) AS [Luft],
  SUM(Case when [Source] = 'TGL' then [SalesAmount1] else 0 end) AS [TGL],
  SUM(Case when [Source] = 'BHW' then [SalesAmount1] else 0 end) AS [BHW],
  SUM(Case when [Source] = 'WM' then [SalesAmount1] else 0 end) AS [WM]
FROM [dbo].[tblSales]
WHERE [Planung] = 'kosten'

UNION

SELECT 
  'Sales new' AS [Category],
  SUM(Case when [Source] = 'Luft' then [SalesAmount2] else 0 end) AS [Luft],
  SUM(Case when [Source] = 'TGL' then [SalesAmount2] else 0 end) AS [TGL],
  SUM(Case when [Source] = 'BHW' then [SalesAmount2] else 0 end) AS [BHW],
  SUM(Case when [Source] = 'WM' then [SalesAmount2] else 0 end) AS [WM]
FROM [dbo].[tblSales]
WHERE [Planung] = 'kosten'
```

Comment: Reading the post it seems he wants a query which matches his "expectation using pivot".

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to get a row for each source and the sales type first:

```
select * from 
(
        select [Source], [SalesAmount1] as [Sales old], [SalesAmount2] as [Sales new] 
        FROM tblSales
        WHERE [Planung] = 'Kosten' 
) as src
UNPIVOT ([Amount] for [Type] in ([Sales old], [Sales new])) up
```

This gets you

> ```
> Source  Amount  Type       
> ------  ------  ---------  
> LuFt    3000    Sales old  
> LuFt    9000    Sales new  
> LuFt    7000    Sales old  
> LuFt    11000   Sales new  
> TGL     500     Sales old  
> TGL     800     Sales new  
> BHW     1500    Sales old  
> BHW     500     Sales new  
> WM      700     Sales old  
> WM      400     Sales new   
> ...
> ```

Then you can pivot on it more easily:

```
declare @tblSales table(Source varchar(20), SalesAmount1 int, SalesAmount2 int, Planung varchar(30))
insert into @tblSales values ('LuFt', 3000, 9000, 'Kosten')
insert into @tblSales values ('LuFt', 7000, 11000, 'Kosten')
insert into @tblSales values ('TGL', 500, 800, 'Kosten')
insert into @tblSales values ('BHW', 1500, 500, 'Kosten')
insert into @tblSales values ('WM',  700, 400, 'Kosten')

select Source, [SalesAmount1] as [Sales old], [SalesAmount2] as [Sales new] 
FROM @tblSales
WHERE [Planung] = 'Kosten' 

select * from 
(
        select [Source], [SalesAmount1] as [Sales old], [SalesAmount2] as [Sales new] 
        FROM @tblSales
        WHERE [Planung] = 'Kosten' 
) as src
UNPIVOT ([Amount] for [Type] in ([Sales old], [Sales new])) up
PIVOT (sum([Amount]) for [Source] in ([LuFt], [TGL], [BHW], [WM])) p
```

Result:

> ```
> type       LuFt   TGL  BHW   WM   
> ---------  -----  ---  ----  ---  
> Sales old  10000  500  1500  700  
> Sales new  20000  800  500   400
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps,

```
SELECT [Type] as '[]', [Luft], [TGL], [BHW], [WM] FROM 
(
SELECT 'Sales old' as [Type], [SalesAmount1] as [SalesAmount], [Source] FROM [dbo].[tblSales]
UNION
SELECT 'Sales new' as [Type], [SalesAmount2] as [SalesAmount], [Source] FROM [dbo].[tblSales]
) AS SourceTable

PIVOT

(
   SUM([SalesAmount]) 
   FOR [Source] IN ([Luft], [TGL], [BHW], [WM])

) AS PivotTable
```